# Marvel (?) comic book from c. 1960-1970 villain gets exploded by their own bomb

Tags: story-identification, comics

It might have been a Marvel comic book although I don't remember any famous Marvel heroes in it.  So maybe it was in an anthology of science fiction or horror stories comic book.

I think that I probably read it sometime between 1960 and 1970.

The main character wanted to kill someone or a lot of people or maybe the entire human species.  So he built a powerful atomic bomb, possibly called a cobalt bomb.  And he built a space ship and took his bomb out into outer space.

Then he released the bomb - probably with a timer or maybe a contact trigger - and watched it float away from his ship.

Then he saw the bomb heading back to his ship, attracted by the ship's gravity or magnetism.  And instead of turning on the engines to get away he exclaimed:

"No! This can not be!"

But it could be and it was.  The bomb struck and exploded.

As far as I remember nobody on Earth was harmed but some people saw a pretty flash of light in the sky.

Obviously the height that the bomb exploded must have been many times the destructive radius of the explosion, or else at least one person on Earth would have been harmed.  So I don't know what the bomber's plan was.  Maybe he expected the bomb to take many hours to fall much closer to Earth before exploding and expected to get much farther from Earth before the bomb exploded.

So can anyone remember this comic book story?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"[The Man Who Blew Up The Earth](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Tales_to_Astonish_Vol_1_29)" from *Tales to Astonish* Volume 1 #29

> A jilted Quasimodo-like scientist named Elias Cragston devotes all his energy into producing a cobalt bomb which is so powerful that it can shatter the Earth. He wants to destroy all of mankind for jeering at his ugliness. He sneaks on board a rocket that is going into orbit and releases the bomb. However, Elias forgets about the lack of gravitational pull, and the bomb is caught in Earth's orbit until it detonates against the side of the rocket. On Earth, the woman who laughed at him when he proposed marriage gazes skyward at the explosion and exclaims, "Isn't it the most beautiful sight you've ever seen?"

[image: Hoist by his own petard] <sub>Click to embiggen</sub>

Found with a search for `marvel comic "cobalt bomb"`, which turned up [this list](https://www.comicbookfx.com/result.php?tagexact=1&tags=cobalt%20bomb) of comic book sound effects involving a cobalt bomb, whereupon I looked up each instance.

Comment: This must be the answer to my question.  Except that it dosen't contain the line "No! This cannnot be!" which I remember.  So I guess that line is from another comic book or made up by my falty memory.